# Swift 3 Upload image to PHP Fail

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

Upload image fail
I send image by POST to php

[image]

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
}

@IBAction func selectPicture(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let ImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    ImagePicker.delegate = self
    ImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    self.present(ImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)       
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    image.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func upload_request(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    UploadRequest()
}   

func UploadRequest()
{
    let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/imgJSON/img.php")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()        

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    if (image.image == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image!)

    if(image_data == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    let body = NSMutableData()

    let fname = "test.png"
    let mimetype = "image/png"

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append(image_data!)
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    request.httpBody = body as Data        
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {            (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        print(dataString)            
    }
    task.resume()       
}    

func generateBoundaryString() -> String
{
    return "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
}
```

In PHP

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "image.png")) {
echo "File uploaded: ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second screenshot shows the problem:
this is the server reply with a PHP warning, the apache/php user does not have the permissions to move the uploaded image to the targetdirectory in your case this would be the root directory (/) - because you did not specify a directory/path where to store the image. See [Example 1](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) of the PHP documentation.

So you should create an upload directory (e.g. *mkdir /Appli.../htdocs/uploads* , set the correct permissions (for dev purpose *chmod -R 777 uploads*) and specify in your PHP the target directory:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/Appli.../htdocs/uploads/image.png")) { ...
```

Comment: it not work
in php 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/image.png")) {
    echo "File uploaded: ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
}

i run application but show 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gd87ym4yfr0lao3/%E0%B8%88%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%88%E0%B8%AD%202559-09-21%20%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B2%2017.14.01.png?dl=0

Comment: you are now saving the image directly to your htdocs /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ please try the following:

Comment: Sorry I was intererupted here the full comment:
you are now saving the image directly to your htdocs folder: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs, please try the following on your **terminal**:

mkdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploads
&&
chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploads

and then use on **PHP**:

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploads/image.png"))

Comment: not work, i test HTML form send image to PHP https://www.dropbox.com/s/1br0v98znwlainr/3.png?dl=0

Comment: ahh ok the directory already exists, so just do:

sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imgJSON

if this is the directory where you want to store your images.